# How to migrate spring annotation-based Hibernate code to Java EE

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

First of all: here is my code: https://github.com/s1ddok/todosapp

I'm learning java technologies. I forked a demo project on github and for now my goal is to add login (user specific todos) and hibernate mysql stuff. I successfully done it for `-spring` version. Now I want to do the same stuff for java ee.

How do I migrate annotation based hibernate code (Entities and config) to java ee? Is it possible to simply reuse them? I heard that you have to use xml config with Java EE, is it true?

My requirement is to use same `front-end` (backbone) and same database for both `-spring` and `-javaee`. This is my goal. I have to implement same-functionality REST service with spring and javaee.

I'm completely stuck with that.

Comment: With Java EE meaning that you want it to do in Ejb?

Comment: It means i want to migrate my rest controller from spring to servlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JavaEE you do not have to use much XML configs (in comparison with the old J2EE), but you can do most things with annotations.

Regarding database access you can still use Hibernate (**JPA**), since JPA is part of the JavaEE spec. The Json annotations like `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo` are not part of JavaEE spec (yet), so you might have to use **JAXB** instead.

Regarding REST you want to have a look at **JAX-RS**. The annotations are different in comparison to Spring (`@ApplicationPath, @Path, @GET, ...`), but you should be able to achieve the same result for you application.

For security (login) you have to look at application server specific options, since this be will standarized only in JavaEE 8 (JSR 375).

Comment: what about hibernate config? is there a way to use annotations for that?

Comment: You can configure entities with annotations, but you need a persistence.xml to configure the persistence unit.

Comment: Stick to the [JPA 2.1 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html). Hibernate, Eclipselink, OpenJPA, ... just implement this spec. To configure the database connection it depends on the application server you want to use. For example for Glassfish/Payara you want to have a look at JDBC connection pool / resource.